# Wann ist die Eindeutschung neuer Lehnworte sachgemäß, wann nicht?

Tags: technical-terminology, loanword, anglicism

In einem wissenschaftlichen Text soll ein Lehn- oder Zitatwort verwendet werden, das keine deutsche Entsprechung hat.

Nach welchen *Regeln* wird entschieden, ob dieses Wort z. B. nach den Regeln der deutschen Grammatik flektiert oder gar komplett eingedeutscht wird? Wann ist eine Verwendung, die z. B. Flexion zur Folge hat, zu vermeiden? *(„Sein Artikel wurde ausführlichem Peer-Review unterzogen“* statt *„Sein Artikel war ausführlich Peer-reviewt“.)*

Ich nehme in dieser Frage an, dass sich bisher keine Form durchgesetzt hat.

Einige Beispiele (keines davon *besonders* treffend):

- [Trunkieren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunkierung_%28Datenbank%29) (Truncating – Eindeutschung scheint absolut akzeptabel)
- [Stemming](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) (etwa: Wortstammbildung)
- [Tokenisierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenisierung) (Tokenisation)
- [Type-Token-Relation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-Token-Relation)
- [Duck-Typing](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck-Typing) (tatsächlich keine dt. Entsprechung – Eindeutschung scheint lachhaft)

Kurz: Welche allgemeinen Regeln gibt es für den Grad der Eindeutschung nicht etablierter Lehnworte?

Comment: Hm... Intuition?

Comment: Für Fälle, in denen sich noch nichts durchgesetzt hat, kann es quasi per definitionem keine Regeln geben.

Comment: ein Beispiel, dass sich sehr durchgesetzt hat: *downloaden*. (Deutsche Entsprechung: herunterladen) Auch häufig flektiert: Ich habe es gedownloadet / downgeloadet...

Comment: Nicht nur der Name, auch da Prinzip des Duck-Typing sind mit der Deutschen Kultur einfach unvereinbar. Hier muss doch ales seine Schublade haben in der es steckt :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Für wissenschaftliche Arbeiten habe ich von mehr als einem Professor immer folgenden Rat bekommen: Wenn das Wort nicht im Duden steht, dann wird es einmal vor der ersten Benutzung erläutert und dann nur in Kursivschrift (oder anders kenntlich gemacht) verwendet und niemals flektiert. In diesem Falle würde ich mich also für „Sein Artikel wurde ausführlichem *Peer-Review* unterzogen“ entscheiden. Allerdings könnte man bei Peer-Review sicher auch eine deutsche Entsprechung finden.

Comment: Lt. Wikipedia kann man *Begutachtung durch Ebenbürtige* für peer-review sagen. Kommt mir alles ziemlich Spanisch vor...

Comment: naja ... also spanisch ist das nun auch nicht aber die Frage war ja auch nicht nach einem deutschen Äquivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Die Beispiele stammen alle aus dem IT-Bereich, in welchem ich auch tätig bin.

Hier sind einige große Firmen wie Siemens und Microsoft sprachprägend. Bei ihren Handbüchern bemüht man sich konsequent, neue deutsche Termini zu schaffen.

Schlimmster Auswuchs ist der Ersatz des Ctrl-Keys durch die Strg-Taste, die man genauso gut auch Kontrolltaste hätte nennen können.

Positiver sind die Bemühungen der großen Fachredaktionen von CT und Computer Bild zu sehen, die sich um einen gepflegten Sprachgebrauch bemühen.

In meiner Umgebung stelle ich bei gesprochener Sprache eine Tendenz, englische Begriffe gemäß deutschen Regeln anzupassen, fest. In der Schriftsprache werden häufiger die vorhandenen Eindeutschungen verwendet.

Comment: Dass sich Microsoft konsistent um deutsche Begriffe kümmert ist aber übrigens relativ neu – noch in Windows XP kam im Update-Text das Wort „gedownloadet“ vor. Irgendwann (kurz vor SP2, glaube ich) wurde die deutsche Community mal gefragt, ob sie Anmerkungen hätten und da haben wir dann inständig gebeten, dass die doch bitte mal vernünftiges Deutsch schreiben sollen. Daraufhin wurde das dann geändert. :-)

Comment: Kontrolltaste wäre übrigens in diesem Kontext falsch. Die Taste dient ja der *Steuerung* (= Steuern einer Maschine), nicht der *Kontrolle* (= Polizeikontrolle, Kontrolle einer Klassenarbeit, Kontrolle durch einen totalitären Staat). Und dass die Bemühungen von c't positiv zu sehen sind kann ich auch nicht unterschreiben. Dort wird z.B. seit Ewigkeiten penetrant „DNA“ statt „DNS“ geschrieben, was bis vor sehr kurzer Zeit in der deutschen Fachwelt üblich war.

Comment: Argl... c't und Computer-Bild gleichwertig in einem Satz... <nervösesAugenzucken />

Comment: DNS := Domain Name Service, DNA := Desoxyribunukleinsäure vielleicht eher bei Technology Review/Telepolis? :)

Comment: Ich kenne Strg schon aus Büchern über den C64, mag mich aber täuschen. Irgendwo wird von MS sogar das am-Progressiv verwendet, ich meine, es sei "am drucken".

Comment: Ich dachte immer, STRG steht für _Störung_.